# FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:9: error: cannot find symbol import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Note: /opt/sdk/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.12.1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/cloudfirestore/CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /opt/sdk/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.12.1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/cloudfirestore/CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: /opt/sdk/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_analytics-3.0.2/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebaseanalytics/FirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /opt/sdk/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_analytics-3.0.2/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebaseanalytics/FirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
/opt/sdk/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.11.1+5/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebaseauth/FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
                          ^
  symbol:   class NonNull
  location: package androidx.annotation
/opt/sdk/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.11.1+5/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebaseauth/FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
                          ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: package androidx.annotation
/opt/sdk/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.11.1+5/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebaseauth/FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:764: error: cannot find symbol
  private void reportException(Result result, @Nullable Exception exception) {
                                               ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: class FirebaseAuthPlugin
/opt/sdk/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.11.1+5/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebaseauth/FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:668: error: cannot find symbol
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                            ^
  symbol:   class NonNull
  location: class FirebaseAuthPlugin.SignInCompleteListener
/opt/sdk/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.11.1+5/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebaseauth/FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:687: error: cannot find symbol
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                            ^
  symbol:   class NonNull
  location: class FirebaseAuthPlugin.TaskVoidCompleteListener
/opt/sdk/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.11.1+5/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebaseauth/FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:705: error: cannot find symbol
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                            ^
  symbol:   class NonNull
  location: class FirebaseAuthPlugin.GetSignInMethodsCompleteListener
/opt/sdk/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.11.1+5/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebaseauth/FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:540: error: cannot find symbol
              public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                                      ^
  symbol: class NonNull
/opt/sdk/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.11.1+5/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebaseauth/FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:617: error: cannot find symbol
          public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                                          ^
  symbol: class NonNull
8 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':firebase_auth:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

  > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 15s

---

Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: this is an android x issue. Try using a lower version of the firebase auth plugin. For more details see this https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility

Answer (score 11):

This is what helped me:

- Go to android/app/build.gradle file and change compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 28 (they were probably 27)
- Go to android/gradle.properties file and add the following lines:
  `android.useAndroidX=true
  android.enableJetifier=true`

This will switch your app to using androidx, and in turn solve this problem.

---

from here:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27090#issuecomment-457926860